# Dynamically adding a new column in controller action Cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to add a new Column to my database table dynamically from controller.

Here is what i'm doing:

In my **CategoriesController** action i'm getting the table instance of an other table and adding column to it:

```
$nodes = TableRegistry::get('Nodes');
    $nodesTable = $nodes->schema();
    $nodesTable->addColumn('f_name', 'string', [
        'default' => null,
        'null' => true,
    ]);
    debug($nodes->schema());
```

The debug information shows that the column is added but its not added to the database. 
I cant find any update or save method that make changes in the database like we have in migrations.

I'm quite new to Cakephp so any help about what i'm doing wrong or what i need to do would be great.